# How to display open/save dialog asp net mvc 4

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am able to request a file and also have it returned.
I don´t know how to display a open/save dialog box.

**View:**

```
function saveDocument() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Operacao/saveDocument',
        type: 'POST',
        DataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            //I get the file content here
        }
    });
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public void saveDocument() {
    Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=SailBig.jpg");
    Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/MyPDFs/Pdf1.pdf"));    
    Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you cannot download a file in a browser async, just redirect the user to the action and the browser will open a save dialog window. In asp.net mvc you could have an action method to download a file resulting in a `FileResult` with the `File` method of the base controller.

```
public ActionResult SaveDocument()
{   
    string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/MyPDFs/Pdf1.pdf");
    string contentType = "application/pdf";

    //Parameters to file are
    //1. The File Path on the File Server
    //2. The content type MIME type
    //3. The parameter for the file save by the browser

    return File(filePath, contentType, "Report.pdf");
}
```

Comment: It is downloading automatically without asking. The dialog does not show!

Comment: That is browser dependent. If you set to download automatically to a given folder, the browser will download automatically. Firefox and Chrome are some browsers with this behavior.

Comment: @JoãoSimões Is there any way to `get Save As dialogue box` to appear in Firefox and Chrome? I am yet searching for solution!

Comment: For Chrome: In Settings, Click Show advanced settings and scroll down to the "Downloads" section. To change the default download location, click Change and select where you'd like your files to be saved. If you'd rather choose a specific location for each download, select the "Ask where to save each file before downloading" checkbox.

Comment: For Firefox: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file

Answer (score 1):

One way to force firefox (doen't work for chrome) to open the save dialogue is to set the contenttype to "application/octet-stream" and give it a filename with the correct extension.

```
public ActionResult SaveDocument()
{   
    string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/MyPDFs/Pdf1.pdf");
    string contentType = "application/octet-stream";  //<---- This is the magic

    //Parameters to file are
    //1. The File Path on the File Server
    //2. The content type MIME type
    //3. The parameter for the file save by the browser

    return File(filePath, contentType, "Report.pdf");
}
```